Could sound be used to levitate or destroy objects in combat
I am working on a near future world where mages are really just people with a very good understanding of math and science, which they use to achieve feats that seem impossible to most of the population that has lost a lot of knowledge about math and science. The main magic ability I am trying to replicate is the power to levitate objects fore use in combat. Disregarding ear damage could someone use sound to levitate and throw objects around them? If so what would the major limitations be and how might it work? I am also open to alternative suggestions if sound levitation is completely unviable.
(also energy concerns and manufacturability are not a concern)

Wikipedia's acoustic levitation article has a better video than I've seen before, and can give you other pointers.

For future reference, you're not asking a worldbuilding question, you're asking an engineering question better suited for [physics.se] or [engineering.se]. We'll use science to rationalize the development of a world rule (if you read the tag wiki, [tag:science-based] scopes the answer, not the question), but we don't engineer solutions in the Real World. Thus, your question should have explained what's different about your world ("near future" isn't enough), then asked us to help rationalize acoustical levitation in that world. ... (*Continued*)

... The problem is that "viable" is meaningless to us. Everything is viable in your imaginary world (see [help/on-topic]) and we don't help build the Real World because it's already built.... Also, please remember you're allowed one and only one question. Asking more than one question is literally a reason to close the question.

My suggestion: Pick an object. Clearly define it's properties - mass, size and location relative to the mage and the target. Clearly define what you want to happen, what effect you wish to create. Then ask how to accomplish it with sound. - This will give us a well-defined problem to solve without all the guesswork and assumptions that would lead to a multitude of vague answers.

I will take this into consideration and just my question accordingly thank you.

The shockwave from an explosion can be reproduced with a sufficiently power "speaker" and cause damage, at least damage to living tissues, such as the ears or internal organs. However, the same "speaker", regardless how strong it is, cannot levitate an object. The shockwave can, at best, kick the object.
To understand this, here is a demonstration of acoustic levitation.
How does acoustic levitation really work? - The action Lab
The idea is to create a standing wave. A standing wave is created when the sound wave bouncess off of a wall. If the distance from the sound source to the wall is an integer multiple of the half wavelength, you get a standing wave: It is the result of interference between the sound wave and the one bouncing back to the source. The "node" is a location where the pressure is constant and normal and the anti-node is where the pressure swings according to the sound amplitude. The anti-node repels the object that approaches it because of the higher pressure, so it is stuck between two anti-nodes.
Obviously, levitating the object would require a vertical setup. That means the reflecting surface is above the sound source and the levitated object hovers between them. You cannot just levitate objects in the open, so the only possible way is to create a "trap" which lifts off the enemy troops when they pass above it.

No, and Yes, in That Order
Acoustic levitation is a real and fascinating thing that might allow contactless assembly of electronics and other similar applications in the near future.
But, as with many things, the square-cube law is not your friend.  The more massive the object, the greater the pressure differential on its affected surfaces is required, and thus the greater the intensity of sound that is required.  The Earth's atmosphere can only support sounds up to 194 dB.  So you might be able to levitate and throw a baseball, if you had transducers positioned properly, but you're not going to be throwing cars or gold bars.
What about "destroy"?
Here, we've got way more options.  Intense sound in the audible range can, of course, cause pain or deafen individuals.  Sufficiently intense sound (180dB and above) can cause damage to internal organs.
Depending on their materials and construction, objects can also be subject to damage due to targeting their resonant frequencies.  Memorex famously did this with a wine glass and a recording of Ella Fitzgerald.
Converging sound waves can also induce shockwaves that can do damage to their immediate surroundings; this technique is used non-invasively to break up gallstones.
Summary
You could levitate pencils or microchips.  You can destroy certain objects, damage others, and harm or kill humans.  But you're not going to be lifting and throwing anything that you couldn't more easily lift and throw by other means.

Can a sound/shock wave of  210 decibels lift a car. Also does acoustic levitation still apply for shock waves like can shock waves be used for acoustic levitation

Again, @Coolcats112 you cannot sustain sounds of 210 decibels in atmosphere.  Shock waves, by their nature, disrupt the media in which they operate, so you can't use them for levitation.

aw man that sucks

I know you're not supposed to thank people in the comments but this was a very good answer. What would the atmosphere have to be like to let you move the heavier objects with sound? If there was less gravity would that help, or is it like more atmosphere means a bigger planet which means more gravity, which would make you need a stronger atmosphere / bigger atmosphere?
